how to change jruby-complete version in spring boot build
I am trying to build spring boot version 3.1.x.
I am under corporate firewall and using proxy to download the dependencies.
proxy server also check if the version of jar being downloaded has any known vulnerabilities. if it has known vulnerabilities, it blocks the download.
spring boot version 3.1.x is using version 9.2.14.0 of jruby-complete which has vulnerability and it is blocked from being downloaded.
following is the error message.
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':spring-boot-project:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:asciidoctor'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':spring-boot-project:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:__$$asciidoctorj_asciidoctor$$__r'.
Could not download jruby-complete-9.2.14.0.jar (org.jruby:jruby-complete:9.2.14.0)
Received status code 403 from server: -------------------->>> Requested item is quarantined -------------------->>>

How to change the version of jruby-complete? I tried to search for it in the code but there is no reference to it.
or is to possible to skip the asciidoctor task? i tried building with "-x asciidoctor" but error persist.
